# How do I open a program directly to a specific virtual desktop with powershell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, virtual-desktop

I am setting up a monitor screen. Because of the compatibility with different web pages viewed running a tab switcher in Firefox or Chrome is not working well for all websites.  I am trying to create a virtual desktop switcher to open a new process window (browser specific to the website displayed) in different virtual desktops on Windows 10. I found a PowerShell command set to create the virtual desktops and think I have an infinite loop setup for the switching between the desktops while waiting a specified time between them.

How do I open the process in the specific desktop? I didn't want to try to move the process because I may need to open more than one Firefox browser, for instance, and figured it would just pull all the Firefox processes to the same desktop which defeats the purpose.

Link to VirtualDesktop.ps1: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-commands-to-d0e79cc5

The script so far:

```
# Change to VirtualDesktop powershell folder
cd C:\Users\monitor1\Downloads\VirtualDesktop

# Load commands (assumes VirtualDesktop.ps1 is in the current path) 
. .\VirtualDesktop.ps1

# Create a new virtual desktop and switch to it 
New-Desktop | Switch-Desktop

$path = "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" 
Start-Process $path -ArgumentList 'https://system.url.com'

# Create a new virtual desktop
New-Desktop | Switch-Desktop

$path = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
Start-Process $path -ArgumentList 'http://solarwinds.url.com'

#switch between desktops with a 30 second pause
$VD = 1
while ($VD = 1) {
    $DesktopList = @(1..2)
    foreach ($DesktopNum in $DesktopList) {
        Switch-Desktop -Desktop $DesktopNum
        Start-Sleep -s 30
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find the answer? Answer below does not seem to mention virtual screen name/number and it seems that it requires username/password in script, which is indeed not acceptable. (sorry for newbie question, puzzled linux user here)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run "Task View", you can click the [Task View] icon on the taskbar1, or you can press the Windows logo key + tab on the keyboard. To create a virtual desktop, select New desktop. It is possible to open the apps you wish to use on different desktops at the same time

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for [psexec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)

PSExec \COMPUTER_IP_ADDRESS -u UsernameWithAccessToSystem -p Password %Command to run here%